# Telerik report filtering

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-reporting

I am using Telerik report for an ASP.MET MVC 3 application.

I need to filter data based only on time not date time.  Telerik report only support type date time as report parameter.

So how can i implement filtering data based only on time?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Would you have UI that would allow user to select the filter, if yes then you would need to use a datetimepicker widget external to the report viewer which would keep the Time part. Then you can set the report parameter values programmatically.

(additional)You can also create a public report property which would be used to filter the report and this way you're basically skipping the built-in report parameters. See http://tv.telerik.com/watch/reporting/video/telerik-reporting-design-time-support-for-parameterized-queries.

Comment: In telerik report setting the parameter as DateTime and its property visible true,it shows a calender in UI when we running the report.Already i have a date based search.I also need a time based search.How can i implement this in telerik report?

Comment: already explained that you would have to stay away from the built-in parameter UI, as it strips the time part.